# Line draw on “even-q” vertical flat topped hex grid

Tags: algorithm, line-of-sight, hexagonal-grid

I'm trying to implement a Line Draw or Line of Sight algorithm for my hex boardgame. Upon reading several different solutions from most common places like the [Hex Bible](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons), none of the algorithms adapted to my grid config (even-q as stated in Hex Bible) work.

Reference image:

[image: reference]

What I want is an algorithm that given hex A and hex B returns all hexes that would be crossed by a line going from the center of A to the center of B, and in case of diagonal, going right through a division it selects both sides of it. As in A(0,1) and B(2,1) => {[0,1][1,1][1,0][2,1]} for horizontal and A(1,0) B(0,2) => {[1,0][0,1][1,1][0,2]} for diagonal.

An in-game example: character in A(0,1) shoots arrow towards B(6,1), the arrow will check for collision in Step 1: [1,1][1,0], Step 2: [2,1], Step 3: [3,1][3,0], Step 4: [4,1], Step5: [5,1][5,0], Step 6: [6,1]

After a sleepless night I have come up with 3 different solutions: two adapted and one of my own. None of them gives perfect results because the math is flawed, so I would like some help.

All three solutions can be found and tested by downloading [my git project][3]. The class is found at com.wartricks.tools.MapTools.java

Algorithm 1 as per hex bible:

```
public Array<Pair> getLOSCells(int x, int y, int x0, int y0) {
    final Array<Pair> highlights = new Array<Pair>();
    // PROBLEM! my offset system has 0,0 on the bottom left and is flat-top
    // coord2Offset gives valid results, but they don't translate well
    // for example my 0,1 should be 0,1,-1 but gets 0,-1,1 instead
    // this causes problems with rounding that make the line break
    final int[] cubeCoordsOrigin = MapTools.coordOffset2Cube(x, y);
    final int[] cubeCoordsDestination = MapTools.coordOffset2Cube(x0, y0);
    final int dx = cubeCoordsOrigin[0] - cubeCoordsDestination[0];
    final int dy = cubeCoordsOrigin[1] - cubeCoordsDestination[1];
    final int dz = cubeCoordsOrigin[2] - cubeCoordsDestination[2];
    float distance = Math.max(Math.abs(dx - dy), Math.abs(dy - dz));
    distance = Math.max(distance, Math.abs(dz - dx));
    if (distance > 0) {
        int[] previousCoord = new int[3];
        for (float i = 0; i <= distance; i++) {
            final float currentX = (cubeCoordsOrigin[0] * (i / distance))
                    + (cubeCoordsDestination[0] * (1 - (i / distance)));
            final float currentY = (cubeCoordsOrigin[1] * (i / distance))
                    + (cubeCoordsDestination[1] * (1 - (i / distance)));
            final float currentZ = (cubeCoordsOrigin[2] * (i / distance))
                    + (cubeCoordsDestination[2] * (1 - (i / distance)));
            final int[] currentCoord = roundCubeCoord(currentX, currentY, currentZ);
            if (!currentCoord.equals(previousCoord)) {
                final int[] offsetCoord = MapTools.coordCube2Offset(currentCoord[0],
                        currentCoord[1], currentCoord[2]);
                highlights.add(new Pair(offsetCoord[0], offsetCoord[1]));
                previousCoord = currentCoord;
            }
        }
    }
    return highlights;
}

public static int[] coordOffset2Cube(int x, int y) {
    final int[] coord = new int[3];
    coord[0] = x;
    coord[2] = y - ((x + (x % 2)) / 2);
    coord[1] = -x - coord[2];
    return coord;
}

public static int[] coordCube2Offset(int x, int y, int z) {
    final int[] coord = new int[2];
    coord[0] = x;
    coord[1] = (z + ((x + (x % 2)) / 2));
    return coord;
}

public static int[] roundCubeCoord(double x, double y, double z) {
    float rx = Math.round(x);
    float ry = Math.round(y);
    float rz = Math.round(z);
    final int s = (int)(rx + ry + rz);
    if (s != 0) {
        final float x_err = (float)Math.abs(rx - x);
        final float y_err = (float)Math.abs(ry - y);
        final float z_err = (float)Math.abs(rz - z);
        if ((x_err > y_err) && (x_err > z_err)) {
            rx -= s;
        } else if (y_err > z_err) {
            ry -= s;
        } else {
            rz -= s;
        }
    }
    return new int[] {
            (int)rx, (int)ry, (int)rz
    };
}
```

This one is a mess, it doesn't behave as expected at all:

[image: errors 1]

Algorithm B as per Bresenham's Line Draw:

```
public Array<Pair> getLOSCellsPlanB(int y1, int x1, int y2, int x2) {
    // Works with errors, probably due to being swapped with x and y
    // !!!Designed for even-r pointy-tops
    final Array<Pair> highlights = new Array<Pair>();
    int i; // loop counter
    int ystep, xstep; // the step on y and x axis
    int error; // the error accumulated during the increment
    int errorprev; // *vision the previous value of the error variable
    int y = y1, x = x1; // the line points
    int ddy, ddx; // compulsory variables: the double values of dy and dx
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    highlights.add(new Pair(y1, x1)); // first point
    // NB the last point can't be here, because of its previous point (which has to be verified)
    if (dy < 0) {
        ystep = -1;
        dy = -dy;
    } else {
        ystep = 1;
    }
    if (dx < 0) {
        xstep = -1;
        dx = -dx;
    } else {
        xstep = 1;
    }
    ddy = 2 * dy; // work with double values for full precision
    ddx = 2 * dx;
    if (ddx >= ddy) { // first octant (0 <= slope <= 1)
        // compulsory initialization (even for errorprev, needed when dx==dy)
        errorprev = error = dx; // start in the middle of the square
        for (i = 0; i < dx; i++) { // do not use the first point (already done)
            x += xstep;
            error += ddy;
            if (error > ddx) { // increment y if AFTER the middle ( > )
                y += ystep;
                error -= ddx;
                // three cases (octant == right->right-top for directions below):
                if ((error + errorprev) < ddx) {
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y - ystep, x));
                } else if ((error + errorprev) > ddx) {
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y, x - xstep));
                } else { // corner: bottom and left squares also
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y - ystep, x));
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y, x - xstep));
                }
            }
            highlights.add(new Pair(y, x));
            errorprev = error;
        }
    } else { // the same as above
        errorprev = error = dy;
        for (i = 0; i < dy; i++) {
            y += ystep;
            error += ddx;
            if (error > ddy) {
                x += xstep;
                error -= ddy;
                if ((error + errorprev) < ddy) {
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y, x - xstep));
                } else if ((error + errorprev) > ddy) {
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y - ystep, x));
                } else {
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y, x - xstep));
                    highlights.add(new Pair(y - ystep, x));
                }
            }
            highlights.add(new Pair(y, x));
            errorprev = error;
        }
    }
    // assert ((y == y2) && (x == x2)); // the last point (y2,x2) has to be the same with the
    // last point of the algorithm
    return highlights;
}
```

The problem with 2 is that it adds extra squares where it shouldn't because it's calculating for pointy-top hexes.

[image: errors 2]

Algorithm 3 as I like it. It uses some magic numbers because of some offsets in the render system.

```
public Array<Pair> getLOSCellsPlanC(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    final Array<Pair> highlights = new Array<Pair>();
    final int dx = x2 - x1;
    final int dy = y2 - y1;
    final FloatPair origin = this.world2window(x1, y1);
    final FloatPair destination = this.world2window(x2, y2);
    final float dpx = destination.x - origin.x;
    final float dpy = destination.y - origin.y;
    final float distance = 2 * Math.max(Math.abs(dx), Math.abs(dy));
    if (distance > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= distance; i++) {
            final float currentX = ((origin.x + ((dpx * i) / distance)));
            final float currentY = ((origin.y + ((dpy * i) / distance)));
            float posx = ((currentX) / gameMap.colSize);
            float posy = (((currentY) - ((gameMap.rowSize * (posx % 2)) / 2)) / gameMap.rowSize);
            final Pair targetHex = new Pair((int)posx, (int)posy);
            highlights.add(targetHex);
        }
    }
    return highlights;
}
```

Results from A3:

[image: Algorithm 3]

Errors from A3: jumps and inconsistent move ambiguities, only one diagonal behaves the way I want.

[image: Errors 3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In algorithm 1, you're using “even-q” but you should use “odd-q” instead. Your grid is flipped upside down relative to the one on my page, so you want to shift every odd column up instead of every even column down. Change `+ (x % 2)` in `coordOffset2Cube` and `coordCube2Offset` to use `- (x % 2)` instead.

Also, on diagonals, the line drawing algorithm will not hit both sides of the line. It only picks one side. [This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233522/elegant-clean-special-case-straight-line-grid-traversal-algorithm) shows the problem on square grids. You can modify hex-rounding to return both sides when x_err, y_err, z_err have a tie (I haven't tried this). Or you can at each step add offsets in various directions and then round, so that if there's a tie, the offsets will end up finding multiple hexes (I've tried this and it seems to work, but I haven't written it up yet).

Comment: The problem has been solved thanks to this tips, and I already made my own "rounding" changes. Feel free to check commit 0f0a366 for changes and the final result.